# Is it possible to delete \ac{<word>} around all words, with Vim?

Tags: vim

For a large report I decided to add `\ac{ }` around every single word from the list of abbreviations, however we've now come to that this was a bad idea, and I want to remove them.

I could of course do this semi-automatic with a find-replace for each word in the list of abbreviations, or write a script. But I would rather want to know whether or not there is a magical Vim way of doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this in multiple ways but the easiest is probably a simple search and replace:

```
:%s/\\ac{\([^}]\+\)}/\1/g
```

This will:

1. Search and replace in the whole buffer: `:%s/`
2. Find the left part: `\\ac{`
3. Start a new capture group: `\(..\)`
4. Get every character that isn't `}`: `[^}]\+`
5. Find the right part: `}`
6. Replace all matched characters with the capture group: `/\1`
7. Apply this multiple times on every line: `/g`